# Russian translations for the month "May"

Tags: marklogic

In Russian the translation of the English word for the month of May can be one of two options. If one is saying "the 31st of May" then the word May is translated as "Мая" and if one is saying "May 2014" then the word May should be translated as "май" because it is no longer using "of May".

Using Marklogic's implementation of the fn:format-date function I cannot determine how I can get the "май" version of May.

Here is the function call:

`fn:format-date(xs:date("2014-05-01"), "[MNn] [Y]", 'ru')`

Is there a way to get the "май" version of May or does format-date only ever return "Мая"?

From what I can tell from the documentation for the picture format this is implementation dependent. It may be that XQuery has no way to specify a different version of the month name.

Answer (score 1):

MarkLogic uses the library "ICU" http://site.icu-project.org/ for most Unicode and localization releated features.  Its the best library we know of, but its not perfect by any means.
The library doesn't understand XQuery patterns for date display so there is some complex work to parse out the XQuery patterns then use the lower level API's to get the related data.
Even with that, things like day and date names are more subtle in reality then the library and its internal database can represent.

To get better control you will need to write some or part of your own date time formatter.
You can use the parts that work then do a replace to substitute the parts that dont.
For example you could use

```
let $d := xs:date("2014-05-01"), 
  $f := fn:format-date($d, "%%%%MONTH%%%% [Y]", 'ru') ,
  $final := fn:replace( $f , "%%%%MONTH%%%%" , my-own-month-formatter( $d ) )
```

where you supply a function my-own-month-formatter() that returns the right month name
based on the total date.    Functions for extracting values from date-time fields are available
in xquery as well as functx module.

Here is an example of a customized date name translation function from functx

http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/functx_month-name-en.html

Comment: If you're generally happy but want to address the specific case you described: 
    fn:replace(
      fn:format-date(xs:date("2014-05-01"), "[MNn] [Y]", 'ru'),
      "Мая",
      "май"
    )